# Range.InsertXML using Transform

Tags: vba, xslt, ms-word

I am using `Range.InsertXML` to add formatted content to an existing MS Word document.

AFAICT, the method .InsertXML takes parameters XML as a string and XLST (Transform) as a variant; however [the documentation for .InsertXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-insertxml-method-word) is lacking in that it does not provide an example that includes the use of Transform.

In responding to this question: [Range.InsertXML throws when inserting Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48285729/3451115) Cindy Meister linked to [an excellent resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml#main) that explains lotd about Words XML and how to use it, but I still can't find any examples where Transform is used.

**What I am trying to do** is the same as in this question: [XSLT create table with dynamic number of rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32746779/3451115) (but using VBA).

From that question this is the modified code that I expected to work:

```
Sub testInsertXML()

    Dim strXML As String
    Dim XSLT As Variant

    strXML = "<Movies><Genre name=""Action""><Movie><Name>Crash</Name><Released>2005</Released></Movie></Genre><Genre name=""Drama""><Movie><Name>The Departed</Name><Released>2006</Released></Movie><Movie><Name>The Pursuit of Happyness</Name><Released>2006</Released></Movie></Genre><Genre name=""Comedy""><Movie><Name>The Bucket List</Name><Released>2007</Released></Movie></Genre></Movies>"

    XSLT = "<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"" xmlns:w=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml""><xsl:output indent=""yes""/><xsl:template match=""/""><w:document><w:body><w:tbl><w:tr><xsl:for-each select=""/Movies/Genre""><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t><xsl:value-of select=""@name""/></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></xsl:for-each></w:tr><!-- Movies? --><xsl:call-template name=""movies-row""><xsl:with-param name=""i"" select=""1""></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></w:tbl></w:body></w:document></xsl:template><xsl:template name=""movies-row""><xsl:param name=""i""/><w:tr><xsl:for-each select=""/Movies/Genre""><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t><xsl:choose><xsl:when test=""count(Movie) >= $i""><xsl:value-of select=""concat(Movie[$i]/Name, ' (', Movie[$i]/Released, ')')""/></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><!-- empty cell --></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></xsl:for-each></w:tr><xsl:if test=""/Movies/Genre[count(Movie) > $i]"">" & _
           "<xsl:call-template name=""movies-row""><xsl:with-param name=""i"" select=""$i + 1""/></xsl:call-template></xsl:if></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>"

    Selection.Range.InsertXML strXML, XSLT

End Sub
```

I have added double quotes to the strings (so that the quotes appear correctly when using debug.print) AND I have added additional tags as described [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/2636).

I think I'm not setting up the Transform correctly. If the Transform is set to vbnullstring everything works. Otherwise I get an error:

> XML markup cannot be inserted in the specified location

Basically, as an answer to this question, I'd like a minimal example showing how to use `.InsertXML` using Transform.

Comment: I get the feeling that the transform result may not be valid Word Open XML. If you create an XML string that uses exactly the structure you specify in the xslt (especially the namespaces) can that be inserted using InsertXML or does it result in the same error? Referring to the article to which you link, take a close look at *Simplified Office Open Markup": you're missing the outer structures such as <pkg:package>, <pkg:part> and so on. Word *requires* these for inserting Open XML.

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister - yes, if I exclude the Transform and just use the (erm) finalized XML then it will work. Re the missing bit... ugh - thanks <mutter><mutter> - I'll take a closer look  :)   Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working solution:

The original source for the xml appears to be from this [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ee872374(v=office.12)) site. Incidentally, there are also some instructions on how to create an XSLT directly from a MS Word document (well, albeit manually).

At any rate, it's easiest to just to the transform and insert as two separate steps, like this:

```
Sub xmlTest()
    Dim xData As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xTnsf As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xOutp As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Set xData = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xTnsf = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xOutp = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    xData.Load "C:\Temp\MyMovies.xml"
    xTnsf.Load "C:\Temp\MyMovies.xslt"

    xData.transformNodeToObject xTnsf, xOutp
    
    ThisDocument.Range.InsertXML xOutp.XML

    Debug.Print xOutp.XML

End Sub
```